# Show SQL script using graphviz

Tags: sql, mysql, graphviz

I am looking for software can show SQL scripts (MySQL in my case) in visual way. Example every script is a circle in the diagram.  Similar to doxygen but for SQL scripts.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting, simple and funky visualisation of your db, literally in a circle: 
https://github.com/westonruter/schemagraph/blob/master/schemagraph.php
A single php file which produces svg output.

A more comprehensive metadata query tool: http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/ 
this gives you entity relationship diagrams and much more. 
There is a gui if that is your thing: 
http://www.joachim-uhl.de/projekte/schemaspygui/

I found but did not use: 
http://code.google.com/p/mysqlviz/

Answer (score 1):

graphviz allows you to plot graph - if you have entities (Nodes) and connection between entities (Node). What this means is, if you could write a script which will split up sql to different units and relation , then you could create a .dot file use graphviz to create visual.

Answer (score 1):

try http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/ works well if you have foreigns keys, if not is useless.

Answer (score 0):

it exist a plugin to symfony who make this.
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGraphvizPlugin